# Is there a way to know how many a table have been consulted in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, standards, audit

I m developping an application about store management and the dev team wants me to add an update a read counter for every table. For the update I managed to do this, but I want to know if there is a proper solution (standardized) to update a value of a column when a row is selected.

Like for multilanguage we have the i18n, is there any standards for this, or should I after every select launch an update on the read counting column for the selected id(s)?

Comment: I think you should be looking at triggers. They fire off automatically when their events occur.

Comment: there is no trigger for select statement :'(

Comment: When you say "standardized", do you mean based on the standard [ISO/IEC 9075:2016](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL:2016)? Or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the best way that we found is to make the  select statement s in a stored procedures where we update the reading field counter

Answer (score 0):

Use `SHOW OPEN TABLES` command.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/show-open-tables.html